# Connection between Leibniz formula and geometric interpretation of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I've seen that the Leibniz formula of determinants can be reduced to the Laplace expansion through consolidating terms. What I haven't been able to find online is a connection between any of those and the geometric interpretation of determinants, which is the volume (or measure) contained between the parallelopiped formed from the column (or row) vectors. How do I prove that the Leibniz formula, which is based on terms composed of permutations has anything to do with geometric measures?

Comment: Show that the signed volume of a parallelepiped has the same multilinearity properties.

Comment: What are multilinearity properties? And why is that sufficient?

Comment: Check out my [video](https://youtu.be/9IswLDsEWFk) for a simple geometric explanation of both the Leibniz and Laplace expansions.

Comment: @blargoner - thank you, the video was exactly what I needed. You're doing gods work!

Answer (score 2):

As a function from $n \times n$ matrices to scalars, the determinant is *uniquely* determined by the following properties:

- It is [multilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map) as a function of the columns.
- It is [alternating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_multilinear_map), meaning that it vanishes if two of the columns are the same, or equivalently (over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$) that it changes sign if you swap any two columns.
- $\det(I) = 1$.

This is a nice exercise. "Column" can also be replaced with "row" throughout. Once you've proven this, the argument proceeds in two phases:

1. First, show that over $\mathbb{R}$, the signed volume definition of the determinant satisfies all of the above properties.
2. Second, show either that the above properties imply the Leibniz formula, or that the Leibniz formula satisfies the above properties.

Comment: This argument is hinging on the words *uniquely determined*. Why should that be the case?

Comment: @Rohit: that's the exercise. It's fun to work out, I encourage you to try it.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Can you give me some direction?

Comment: Start by showing that the multilinear + alternating properties, when applied to rows, imply that you can perform row reduction and it has the usual effect on the determinant.

Comment: Another confusion is that I'm setting out to prove that "the determinant is uniquely determined by those properties". But I don't know what a determinant is in that context. Without knowing that, I don't know what I'm proving.

Comment: @Rohit: to say that the determinant is *uniquely* determined by the above properties is to say that if you can construct a function $f$ from $n \times n$ matrices to scalars which has the above properties, then it must be equal to the determinant. Now you also need a result telling you how to construct the determinant so you know it actually exists; pick your favorite one.